# How to Iterate over Dynamic JSON keys

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
 "Trials": {
                "Trial 1": "Trial 1",
                "Trial 2": "Trial 2",
                "Trial 3": "Trial 3",
                "Trial 4": "Trial 4",
                "Trial 5": "Trial 5"
            }
```

These are dynamically generated and I am not sure how many `Trials` there may be coming in.

Now I know how to get values when the key is expected, for example:

```
 "Person": {
                "FirstName: "Joe",
                "MiddleName": "B",
                "LastName": "Smith"
            }
```

I would go through each one and:

```
if (!o.isNull("FirstName")) {
    session.first_name= o.getString("FirstName");
}
```

But in the first example, it is dynamic.  I can't exactly hard code the key in.  Is there a better way of getting the values?

Note:  The key will ALWAYS be identical to a value.  In a perfect world, this would just be a normal array -- but I am not in control of how the `JSON` is being sent to me so I need to deal with it as it is above.

Comment: But if you don't know the Key then how will you get the value. I have never come across such a problem

Comment: @hiphopdroid Well, since they (key-value) will always be the same, can I just get the value without knowing the keys?

Comment: For knowing the value you will have to know the keys and without keys you can't access them. I think we are going round in circles :)

Comment: that should be a list, not an object. Anyway, you can use JSONObject.keys() to enumerate the keys in your object.

Comment: Oh yeah @njzk2 totally forgot about `JSONObject.keys()`. So we can use the `Iterator`  it returns to get a list of all the keys and hence the values (as keys and values are the same)

Comment: There is `names` as well, which returns a JSONArray.

Comment: I'm with @njzk2; Trials is modeled incorrectly and should be an array. I would try to get that fixed in the server.

Comment: I just convinced server people to fix this.  So I guess that's the best answer.

Comment: @njzk2 is right about `keys`. I'm working on a project now where this happens; we don't always know the keys coming back to us. To solve this, we turn the JSON into a Map, and get the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but if all your input in the JSON is like "Trials n" then this could work out:

```java
for(JSONobject o: myArrayOfJSONs) {
    int n = 0;
    boolean finished = false;

    while(!finished) {
      if (!o.isNULL("Trial "+ n) {
        //do some stuff
        n++;
      } else {
        finished = true;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or, better: `for(int n=0; !o.isNULL("Trial "+ n); n++) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, but it is not guaranteed to be in this format "Trial X".